# Ubuntu log into certain tty shell as a distinct user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tty, x-server, ubuntu-17.04

I try to start an x server for a certain user on tty5 as root user from tty6. My approach was to log into tty5 as a specific user from command line tty6. Then I would just `chvt` to 5 and `startx` there. Problem is, I have no clue how to login a certain user in a specified tty.

So to put it in a nutshell: Is there a command to change to a certain tty and login there as a distinct user from another tty using root privileges?

Or can I just `startx` for a specified user and virtual terminal?

Edit: I want to use root privileges to login the specified user so that the password ist not asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `openvt` command.
From man page:

> openvt [-c vtnumber] [OPTIONS] [--] command
>
> -c, --console=VTNUMBER
>
> -s, --switch
>
> -u, --user

So you can login and switch to desired tty, and run program automatically.

Comment: Already tried this. It always opens a new tty, whereas I want to access the already existing tty5. Furthermore, although passing a user using the `-u` parameter, when executing `whoami` in the new tty it returns the user who opened the new tty (not the one who was passed). Note: I executed `sudo openvt -s -u tester -- startx` from tty5 and tty n opens. Edit: Passing a command to be executed using `-- [command]` does not work either